# Mobile App - Communicating with an external server

Tags: php, android, mysql, azure, xamarin

I'm building a mobile project that needs to be in constant communication with a server and i need some information . I know how to build local apps but this is the first time that i'm building an app that requires external call to a server / authentication service .

I'm asking for guidance how to proceed and which services/servers to use.

What type of server/database do i need ?
I'm guessing i will be requiring an API service but no idea how to choose/make one.

I want to use azure services/database but i also don't want to be dependent on it. I want to have my own url that i send request to and interact with a server/db that i can later move to another host fairly easily.

I develop websites mostly and i'm familiar with php/laravel + Mysql but i think in this case it will be overkill to create a laravel app simply for the server backend .

The app will be mobile only so i don't expect to have a webpage for it . simply an external server/database where the data will be saved.

First i need an authentication service - where each user will register on the phone which will then be saved in my external server/database . Then when they need to login - they will input the login details on the phone , which will query the esternal server/database and if validated - get their details from the server.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide which kind of server communication you'll need. it's in real time and constant? then you'll need a websocket. It's in bursts when you need to send or get data? then you'll need some kind of webservice (REST, RPC, SOAP). Then you have to evaluate the user load you'll have. And finally, the human resources you'll have.

Based on your question, I think a REST webservice will be more than enough. You may:

-Create a REST service for every group of related resources. Example: the /user URL should handle the signup, login, logout and user update operations.

-Create a method for each one of those operations and handle them. Then, call the method from the REST service class.

-Depending on the amount of users and the technology you're using, create a server to handle the requests, or upload your REST project to a server (tomcat, for example).

-Create an app and consume the REST services from there.

There are tons of tech you can choose for these things. PHP allows creating REST services, I think. Java is a very good choice too, since you can use the same code in both server and android apps. Node.Js is pretty popular, too, since you don't need servers and uses NIO (althought java can do both things using jetty and also has multithreading); golang and scala both have superb performance (golang is a lot more easier to learn, though, and it has no need to use external webservers).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile applications the best will be REST (representational state transfer),becouse is lightweight and flex to use in other technology. I had project which include REST and mobile app and web app and it working very well.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, we usually will build a REST API service for client end. As you are familiar with Laravel, you can refer to http://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-build-restful-apis-using-php-and-laravel/how-to/2014/08/13#apiu for how to build a REST API service with Laravel. Also you can leverage other light 3rd part PHP frameworks to build REST API service.

You can create and develop the application on local and then deploy to Azure Web Apps. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-php-get-started/ for more info.

And there several vendors provide MySQL services on Azure. [ClearDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/cleardb/databases/) is a BaaS on Azure for MySQL. You also can use the VM to host your MySQL Service. E.G. [MySQL by Bitnami](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/docker/mysql-arm/) and [MySQL by Docker](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/docker/mysql-arm/).